# when does Promise.resolve() trigger then() method?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm learning the Promise in js and i have some question about it, here's the code:

```js
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  console.log(0);
  return Promise.resolve(4);
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res)
})

Promise.resolve().then(() => {
  console.log(1);
}).then(() => {
  console.log(2);
}).then(() => {
  console.log(3);
}).then(() => {
  console.log(5);
}).then(() => {
  console.log(6);
})
```

the output is far from what I expected, i thought it would be 0 1 4 2 3 5 6, because i saw this on MDN

> the Promise.resolve() method returns a Promise object that is resolved with a given value

so doesn't the log() method should be triggered right behind number 1?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also even if we replace `Promise.resolve(4)` by `Promise.resolve(4).then(res=>res)`, it works the same. But anymore `then` chaining on the same pushes the `4` to be further in the output.

Comment: If we replace `Promise.resolve(4)` with `Promise.resolve(4).then(res => console.log(res));` then the order is coming as `0 1 4 ....`

Answer (score 2):

Promises aren't being processed directly, but are based on a queue. If the promise completes, the callback is processed in the next processing cycle.

If we were to replace your code with a more verbose one, we would get:

```js
const a = Promise.resolve('a');

const b = a.then(() => {
  console.log('b');
  const c = Promise.resolve('c');
  return c;
});

const ca = b.then((res) => {
  console.log('ca', res)
})

const u = Promise.resolve('u');

const v = u.then(() => {
  console.log('v');
});

const w = v.then(() => {
  console.log('w');
});

const x = w.then(() => {
  console.log('x');
});

const y = x.then(() => {
  console.log('y');
});

const z = y.then(() => {
  console.log('z');
});
```

First pass the code is running top to bottom and not a lot is going on. Two promises are being put in the queue as resolved (`a` and `u`) and nothing is printed. When those are being processed in the next cycle, they queue both `b` and `v`.

Whenever the next cycle is being processed, `b` is first up, logs `"b"` and queues the `c`. After that, `v` is processed, logs `"v"` and queues `w`.

Now, `c` is done, and queues the next `ca` (indirection, because of returning a promise in a promise), but doesn't print anything. And so on.

All the way down, it would looks something like this:

```
// Main tick
// - queue a
// - queue u

// Queue tick
// - resolve a, queues b
// - (log nothing)
// - resolve u, queues v
// - (log nothing)

// Queue tick
// - resolve b, queues c
// - log "b"
// - resolve v, queues w
// - log "v"

// Queue tick
// - resolve c, doesnt log, queues the next (ca)
// - resolve w, queues x
// - log "w"

// Queue tick
// - resolve x, queues y
// - log "x"
// - resolve ca, queues nothing
// - log "ca, c"

// Queue tick
// - resolve y, queues z
// - log "y"

// Queue tick
// - resolve z
// - log "z"
```

I'm not aware whether this is an actual requirement or not, so the order may change if the implementation (browser) decides to process promises directly. I think its unlikely though, as it doesn't encourage fairness and in case of a promise being chained forever and forever this promise would get all the resources assigned to it.

I think the general recommendation is to not depend on the order of promises being completed. Just think of `a.then(b)` as, `b` only happens after `a` is completed, not earlier, and nothing more.

If you require multiple promises to be dependent on each other, use `Promise.all()` or `Promise.any()`.

Comment: Please emphasise **the general recommendation is to not depend on the order of promises being completed**!

Comment: Couple of doubts here. I don’t get why we are queuing the promises. The queuing happens for the callbacks isn’t ? Also in the third **Queue tick**, `CA` is queued before `x` but in the next tick you’re resolving `x` before  `CA` ?

Comment: @LakshyaThakur Yes, the queuing is for promise jobs (resolving thenables, and executing `then` handlers on settled promises) not for "promises" themselves